# Birt hyperlinked reports in single page

Tags: birt

Is it possible to have 3 reports all linked to each other on a single page.

Suppose I have 3 reports. First one drills down to second and second drills down to third i.e. on clicking on first report the second opens and on clicking on second the third opens. Also the second report needs parameters which are passed down from the first report.

Now these reports open up in a new page on clicking. I want the second report to open below second report and third below second. Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** 
Yes

**Longer answer:**
There are a number of different ways of combining reports and linking them to each other in BIRT.  Reports can be delivered as web pages, PDF, Excel, etc. Obviously differing deliveries would want different solutions.

If your are delivering to PDF where the report would be printed, you can essentially put three reports (tables) on the same document which all show the results based on the same parameters

If you are delivering as web pages you can have links in pretty much any place on the report that will jump to another report using a value as a parameter (i.e. Report1 = everything for a week; click on "Monday" see Report2 with just everything from Monday; click on "Noon" and see Report3 with just everything from Noon.